# What's the difference between these two calls to `du -sm`?

Tags: files, disk-usage, utilities

I have a directory that I want to find sizes on. When I run the two following commands, I get very different results. I expect the second to produce results like the first. Any ideas why?

```
$ for d in `echo *`; do du -sm $d; done
5649    archive
2055    archive.git
426     filtered
65      filtered.git
14      filtered.git.bfg-report
$ du -sm *
5649    archive
1       archive.git
426     filtered
1       filtered.git
14      filtered.git.bfg-report
```